# Controller can't jump to view when I customize Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbYiV.png)When i tried to customize error pages, I found that web can't jump to view as expected. When program get "404" response from server, it jumps correctly, but when get "500", it can't works.

I tried to exchange position, and different html files, the result always is the same, "404" part can works well, and "500" don't. And I tried to use redirect, the magical thing happened, it works! Could you please explain it?

```
 @Controller("error")
```

public class GrobalException implements ErrorController {
    //private static final String ERROR_PATH = "/error";

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/error")
public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Object status=request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);
    if(status!=null){
        Integer statuscode=Integer.valueOf(status.toString());
        if(statuscode==HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()){
            return "404";
        }
        else if(statuscode==HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()){
            System.out.println("status is "+statuscode+" intern is "+HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
            return "success";//If i change it to "return "redirect:/success", and define new controller for it, that can jump to success.html 
        }
    }
    return "test";
}

@Override
public String getErrorPath() {
    return "/error";
}
```

}

I supposed to think they are the same thing, why i should use different code to achieve different error code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write complex code.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ErrorController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "404",method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String Page404(ModelMap model) {
    return "404";
  }
    @RequestMapping(value = "500",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Page500(ModelMap model) {
        return "500";
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/500</location>
    </error-page>
```

404.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>This is custom 404 page.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

500.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>This is custom 500 page.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How I can configure it in Springboot?